# Find xpath using selenium tool

Tags: xpath

I need to find out the xpath of one element in the code given below:

```
<div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineTopSection">
<div id="fbProfileCover" class="drop_elem">
<div id="u_jsonp_2_0" class="cover">
<div id="fbTimelineHeadline" class="clearfix">
<div class="_50zj">
<div class="_70k">
<div id="u_jsonp_2_2" class="_6_7 clearfix" data-referrer="timeline_light_nav_top">
<a class="_6-6 _6-7" href="https://www.facebook.com/memusipra">
<a class="_6-6" data-medley-id="pagelet_timeline_medley_about" href="https://www.facebook.com/memusipra/about">
<a class="_6-6" data-medley-id="pagelet_timeline_medley_photos" href="https://www.facebook.com/memusipra/photos">
<a class="_6-6" data-medley-id="pagelet_timeline_medley_friends" href="https://www.facebook.com/memusipra/friends">
<div id="u_jsonp_2_3" class="_6a uiPopover _6-6 _9rx">
</div>
```

I need to findout for Xpath for:

```
<a class="_6-6" data-medley-id="pagelet_timeline_medley_friends" href="https://www.facebook.com/memusipra/friends">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
xpath=//a[@data-medley-id="pagelet_timeline_medley_friends"]
```